# Measure CPU time on Windows using GetProcessTimes

Tags: c++, c, windows, timer, cpu

I would like to measure [CPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit) time of some function. I know how to use `GetProcessTimes`, but I have a problem implementing it with some kind of 'restarting':

Normally, I would do it like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>

double cputimer()
{
    FILETIME createTime;
    FILETIME exitTime;
    FILETIME kernelTime;
    FILETIME userTime;

    if ( GetProcessTimes( GetCurrentProcess( ),
        &createTime, &exitTime, &kernelTime, &userTime ) != -1 )
    {
        SYSTEMTIME userSystemTime;
        if ( FileTimeToSystemTime( &userTime, &userSystemTime ) != -1 )
            return (double)userSystemTime.wHour * 3600.0 +
            (double)userSystemTime.wMinute * 60.0 +
            (double)userSystemTime.wSecond +
            (double)userSystemTime.wMilliseconds / 1000.0;
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    double start, stop;
    long sum = 0L;

    start = cputimer();
    for (long long i = 1; i < 10000000; i++){
        sum += log((double)i);
    }
    stop = cputimer();

    printf("Time taken: %f [seconds]\n", stop - start);

    return 0;
}
```

But with 'reset' I'm not sure if I have right results:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define START    1
#define STOP    0

double cputimer(int reset)
{
    FILETIME createTime;
    FILETIME exitTime;
    FILETIME kernelTime;
    FILETIME userTime;

    double now = 0, then = 0;

    if ( GetProcessTimes( GetCurrentProcess( ),
        &createTime, &exitTime, &kernelTime, &userTime ) != -1 )
    {
        SYSTEMTIME userSystemTime;
        if ( FileTimeToSystemTime( &userTime, &userSystemTime ) != -1 )
            now = (double)userSystemTime.wHour * 3600.0 +
            (double)userSystemTime.wMinute * 60.0 +
            (double)userSystemTime.wSecond +
            (double)userSystemTime.wMilliseconds / 1000.0;
    }

    if(reset)
    {
        then = now;
    }
    else
    {
        then = now - then;
    }

    return then;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    double s;
    long sum = 0L;

    cputimer(START);
    for (long long i = 1; i < 10000000; i++){
        sum += log((double)i);
    }
    s = cputimer(STOP);


    printf("Time taken: %f [seconds]\n", s);

    return 0;
}
```

Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: the code you posted is wrong. to get the expected result the `then` variable should be declared globally, but I would recommend to redesign the `cputimer(int)` function.

Comment: @trylimits: redesign how exactly?

Comment: Often you'll want to measure the CPU-seconds of your process PLUS the kernel.  Actual wall time is also usually of interest, so I usually check both.  If CPU seconds is low and wall time is high, there may be some problem to look into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you go with a simpler solution on Windows like this if your process does not run for too long:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>

double getTime() {
  LARGE_INTEGER freq, val;
  QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);
  QueryPerformanceCounter(&val);
  return (double)val.QuadPart / (double)freq.QuadPart;
}
```

Then you could just use it like this:

```
double d0 = getTime();
// function to measure
double timeInMilliseconds = 1000* (getTime() - d0);
```

You could wrap this into a function to achieve similar behavior as your code.

```
double cputimer(int reset)
{
  static double startTime = 0;
  if(reset)
  {
    startTime = getTime();
    return 0.0;
  } else
  {
    return 1000* (getTime() - startTime);
  }
}
```

UPDATE: If the real intention was to query for the [usertime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) one should replace the `getTime()` function (with the one used by the OP) but the logic in `cputimer()` remains the same.

Comment: QueryPerformanceCounter return wall clock time not cpu time !

Comment: @skyde That is true, I did not realize that the OP might look for the time the program was executing in user space (with more threads this might even return more time than what had actually passed on the 'wall clock'). In this case he could use his own function to get the timestamp and use the `cputimer` function to provide the logic (behaviour) he was looking for.