# Multithreading in MSVC is showing no improvement

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio, c++11

I am trying to run the following code to test the speedup I can get on my system, and check that my code is mult-threading. Using gcc on linux, I get a factor of about 7. Using Visual Studio on Windows, I get no improvement. In MSVS 2012, I set /Qpar and /MD ... am I missing something? What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#ifdef WIN32
    #include <windows.h>
    double getTime() {
      LARGE_INTEGER freq, val;
      QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);
      QueryPerformanceCounter(&val);
      return 1000*(double)val.QuadPart / (double)freq.QuadPart;
    };
    #define clock_type double
#else
    #include <ctime>
    #define clock_type std::clock_t
    #define getTime std::clock
#endif
static const int num_threads = 10;

//This function will be called from a thread
void f()
{
   volatile double d=0;
   for(int n=0; n<10000; ++n)
     for(int m=0; m<10000; ++m)
       d += d*n*m;
}


int main()
{
    clock_type c_start = getTime();
    auto t_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::thread t[num_threads];
    //Launch a group of threads
    for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) {
        t[i] = std::thread(f);
    }
    //Join the threads with the main thread
    for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) {
        t[i].join();
    }
    clock_type c_end = getTime();
    auto t_end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::cout << "CPU time used: "
          << 1000.0 * (c_end-c_start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC
          << " ms\n";
    std::cout << "Wall clock time passed: "
          << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t_end - t_start).count()
          << " ms\n";

    std::cout << "Acceleration factor: "
          << 1000.0 * (c_end-c_start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC / std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t_end - t_start).count() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

**The output using MSVS is:**

CPU time used: 1003.64 ms

Wall clock time passed: 998 ms

Acceleration factor: 1.00565

**In Linux, I get:**

CPU time used: 5264.83 ms

Wall clock time passed: 698 ms

Acceleration factor: 7.54274

EDIT 1: increased size of matrix in f() from 1000 to 10000.

EDIT 2: added getTime() function using QueryPerformanceCounter, and included #define's to switch between std::clock() and getTime()

Comment: For starters, 50 ms is way to low, make the test bigger.

Comment: ok, I had it higher before but tuned it down to see the effect on a smaller problem. Updating...

Comment: I ought to frazzle you at least a little bit that roughly equal wall clock time is "x7 acceleration".  You can guess which C++11 function isn't conformant yet.

Comment: Are you saying this because my smaller problem had times that were on the order of terms of ms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On MSVC, `clock` returns [wall time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4e2ess30.aspx) and is thus not standards compliant.

Comment: WinAPI has `GetProcessTimes`.

Comment: When searching for an example using GetProcessTimes, I found this timer [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19378805/measure-cpu-time-on-windows-using-getprocesstimes), which I am using to model my Win32 timer. I am updating the original post, which leaves the basic question unanswered: why doesn't the MSVC version seem to be multithreading?

Comment: Please re-read carefully the entire page you are linking. `QueryPerformanceCounter` returns wall clock, not CPU time. Use `GetProcessTimes`. You need to add user and kernel times together.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I rewrote it with timers in each thread and found a similar acceleration factor with the update code.